# Can't upload and store images in local storage and in database (Php Laravel)

Tags: php, html, ajax, laravel

So im building my own website and i have this feature wherein a logged-in user can upload and change his avatar. it is my first time doing this so i am having a hard time making this work. i'll provide the codes below, you guys might see the faults that i dont know. it will be greatly appreciated if you can provide links that will help me improve. thanks in advance!

**Blade.php file**

```
<form method='POST' action="{{ route('image-upload')  }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   @csrf
     <div class=" overflow-auto" style="padding-top:5%">>
      <div class="p-3">
       <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body" >
          <h4 class="card-title text-info"><strong> Attach your picture </strong></h4>
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4">
               <div class="form-group row">
               <label for="step5_picture" class="col-sm-3 text-right control-label col-form-label">Please upload your photo here:</label>
               <div class="col-sm-9">
               <input class="form-control" type="file" value="" id='upload_picture'  >
             </div>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
                
       <a href="/home"  class="btn btn-lg waves-effect waves-light btn-success" id="btn-next"  style="float:right;">Next</a>
      <button class="btn btn-lg waves-effect waves-light btn-info" id="btn-upload"  style="float:right; margin-right:10px;">Upload</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

**Ajax code**

```
$("#btn-upload").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = {
        'photo_filename': $('#upload_picture').val(),
        }

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

  
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/image-upload",
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) { 
        }
        }); 
   });

});
```

**Controller.php file** The name of the column in my database is also photo_filename

```
    public function image-upload(Request $request,){
    $data = UserInfoModel::where('app_id', '=' ,Session::get('loginId'))->first();
    $validator=Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'photo_filename' => 'required',
        'photo_filename.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,svg|max:5000'
        ]);
        if($request->hasfile('photo_filename')){
            $data->update([
            'photo_filename' => $request->input('photo_filename')
          ]);
            $photo = $request->file('photo_filename')->getClientOrginalName();
            $destination = public_path() . '/public/image';
            $request->file('photo_filename')->move($destination, $photo);
            return back()->with('success', 'Your image has been successfully uploaded!');
        }   
}
```

**Web.php file**

Route::post('/image-upload',[CustomAuthController::class, 'image-upload'])->name('image-upload');

**I am getting a payload and here it is**
[image]

**No error but still not uploading**
[image]

Comment: your upload use ajax or form action ?

Comment: What's the error or stack trace for your issue?

Comment: Please post router.php also, and in function
public function image-upload is not acceptable, function cannot use dash use underscore instead

Comment: please see the edited version for reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a minimal working example to create file upload in Laravel:

blade file:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ route('save') }}">
    @csrf
    <input type="file" name="image" placeholder="Choose image" id="image">
    <button>Send</button>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public function save(Request $request) {
    $path = $request->file('image')->store('public/images');
    return $path;
}
```

web.php:

```
Route::post('/foobar', [\App\Http\Controllers\FoobarController::class, 'save'])->name('save');
```

Please note Ajax call is not necessary here, since html form will do the [POST call with the CSRF token](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/csrf#preventing-csrf-requests).

Also please note that [using hyphens in function names won't work in php.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)

Comment: **Call to a member function store() on null** even tho i have enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: @CaptainCRAZY input element must have name="image" for image to be included in the request

Comment: yeah its working now, thans for pointing that out antja0!

Comment: np problem. To clarify it doesn't matter if it's an "image" or "foobar" for example. Important thing is that $request->file('foobar') matches the <input name="foobar">

Your browser will form the HTTP POST request based on the elements inside the form, and laravel will try to read the HTTP POST request parameter.

Answer (score 0):

use `FormData` to send file in form, and add `contentType: false` and `processData: false`, you can read function setting `contentType` and `processData` in here https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('photo_filename', $('#upload_picture')[0].files[0])
$.ajax({
  url: "/image-upload",
  type: "post",
  data: formData,
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  success: function(response) {
      
  }
});
```

Comment: still not working and not getting error at the same time. ill edit my post

Comment: @CaptainCRAZY check in Payload and Response tab, what's in there

Comment: Look for the edited version for snippet. The response tab says **Failed to load response data: No content available because the request was redirected**